Migration of module federation to native federation in angular 17 project
I am using angular CLI 17 and module federation 17.
I am trying to migrate to angular new build system. In the existing angular.json, I have this builder
"builder": "ngx-build-plus:browser",

To use the new angular build system, I am migrating the module federation to native federation plug in using this migration guide
I have upgraded module federation to 18.0.4.
But when I run the below command
ng g @angular-architects/module-federation:remove --project  project-name

Getting this error

architect.build.options.main not found for project project-name

my angular.json has this hierarchy
"architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "ngx-build-plus:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/project-name",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts"
          }

I don't understand what is the issue here.

Looks like there was some issue with project name in the command. Now I am passing the project name which is available in angular.json.
After this change, getting the below error  
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'browserTarget')

Ensure you have "browser": "src/main.ts" in angular.json > architect > esbuild > options
Remove the key main and use browser there.
To figure out the issue with browserTarget you'll have to show us the rest of your angular.json file

I have used latest module-federation plug in which solved this issue
@angular-architects/module-federation@18.0.6
Please refer the issue here
https://github.com/angular-architects/module-federation-plugin/issues/646
Thanks to @manfredsteyer who fixed this issue and published the new version of module federation.
